# Angular form submissions issues

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

**This is my signup.html file i want to take only password and username from this form to my controller.but I not able to access form elements through this !**

```
<ion-view view-title="Sign Up">
        <ion-content ng-controller="signup">
            <div class="figure_img">
                <img src="img/logo_image.png">
            </div>
            <form name="myForm">
                <div class="list">
                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Email ID" id="email" name="email" ng-model="formData.email"
                               required>
                        <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required && myForm.email.$dirty">required</span>
                        <span ng-show="!myForm.email.$error.required && myForm.email.$error.email && myForm.email.$dirty">invalid email</span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password"
                               ng-model="formData.password" required>
                        <span ng-show="myForm.password.$error.required && myForm.password.$dirty">required</span>
                    </label>


                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="password_c" name="password_c" ng-model="formData.password_c" valid-password-c required>
                        <span ng-show="myForm.password_c.$error.required && myForm.password_c.$dirty">Please confirm your password.</span>
                        <span ng-show="!myForm.password_c.$error.required && myForm.password_c.$error.noMatch && myForm.password.$dirty">Passwords do not match.</span>

                        </label>

                    <div class="contain-body">
                        <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="signup(myForm)">SignUp</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

**this is my controller for signup**

```
app.controller("signup", function ($scope,$http,$ionicPopup,URL,$ionicLoading,$timeout,$state) {
    $scope.data = {
        email :'',
        password :''
    };

    $scope.signup = function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $http.post(URL.url + '/registration',data)
            .success(function () {
                $ionicLoading.show({template:'<ion-spinner class="spinner-energized"></ion-spinner>Complete your Registration through Email'});
                $timeout(function () {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $ionicHistory.clearCache().then(function() {
                        $state.go('EmailLogin') ;
                    });
                },5000);

            }).error(function (response) {
            $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Sign-Up failed!',
                template:response.errors.email
            });
        });

    }
});
```

how could i take only password and username in my controller ..
so that it gets easy to signup !

Comment: Hey try to pass "formData" on click event like this:

<button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="signup(formData)">SignUp</button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually passing the form controller to your signup method. This is not what you want.

You already got access to your `email` and `password` field values through `formData.email` and `formData.password` in your view, so you can adjust the call to the `signup` by including formData as suggested in the comments.

But as you declare `$scope.data` is your controller, you might want to reuse those instead of formData in your `ng-model` directive of the view, because currently this `data` object does not seem to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object in the function using the data you received. Just do something like `var reqData = { email: data.email, password: data.password };` and then do `$http.post(URL.url + '/registration',reqData)`.

Hope it helps.